# How can I "unstack" my JSON data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have data in a JSON array that looks like this:

```js
[{"TEACHER":3.7},{"STUDENT":1.9}]
```

My desired output is a JSON array that looks like this:

```js
var statements = [
  {
    name: "TEACHER",
    value: 3.7
  },
  {
    name: "STUDENT",
    value: 1.9
  }
];
```

How can I "unstack" the data I have to add the variable labels like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. There might be a more elegant way to do this though.

```js
var x = [{"TEACHER":3.7},{"STUDENT":1.9}];

console.log(unstack(x));

function unstack(stacked){
    var unstacked = [];
    stacked.forEach((element) => {
      unstacked.push({
            name: Object.keys(element)[0],
            value: Object.values(element)[0]
        });
    });
    return unstacked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it the only key your original object has? If that's the case, you can use the only item [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) return. If there are other attributes you could look for a match in the key and process it accordingly.

```js
const input = [{"TEACHER":3.7},{"STUDENT":1.9}];
const output = [];

input.forEach(item => {
    const key = Object.keys(item)[0];

    output.push({name: key, value: item[key]});
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.